# Use docker image in other host in same network

Tags: docker, networking, ip, docker-swarm

I want to use the docker image of one host in another host (raspi) which is in the same network.

Docker image is there is local repository.

Tried with command like:

```
docker pull host2IP:PORT/<<Image>>:<<Tag>>
```

Port I tried : `5000, 3632, 2377, 11000` (referred google to get docker port)

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

Your command above will not work. You need to push your image to a remote docker registry so it will be available on other hosts to pull from.

You can find instructions on how to setup one in the [Official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) or just create an account in DockerHub to push images in there.

If you don't want to setup a private registry or use DockerHub you can always [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) a tarball of the image with `docker save myimage:mytag > myimage.tar`, move the file to the other host, then [load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load) it with `docker load < myimage.tar`

Comment: both raspi are in same network, can we use image from the other host?

Comment: @user3721687 Not directly, you either need to setup a registry and store your images there or use a public one like DockerHub.